# How can I merge multiple files into a single flyway migration?

Tags: database-migration, flyway

I have two sql file

```
/migrations
    v1.0.0__geo-areas-tables.sql
    v1.0.0__geo-areas-data.sql
```

These files are the same version of the migration. How can I apply them within the limits of migration 1.0.0?

P.s. I do not want to use additional scripts combine these files into one.

Answer (score 4):

The rule is simple: one version = one script.

In your case you probably want to name them `v1.0.0.0__geo-areas-tables.sql` and `v1.0.0.1__geo-areas-data.sql` as that is the order you want to guarantee anyway.