# Flyway baseline sql script is too large. Is it possible to have baseline script in multiple files sql scripts?

Tags: flyway

Baseline script gets very large when combining all db schema objects into one. I read in one of the posts that it is possible to split baseline script but it was not explained how.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35857769/how-can-i-merge-multiple-files-into-a-single-flyway-migration

Comment: Not exactly ... here the talk is about baseline script, which, in general, could be much bigger